# My materials look all scratchy and not cool,

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

i've given them a texture but when i render it it looks lame, and kind of scratchy any help?[image: this is what it looks like]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thing to try:

- Increase the lighting on the scene.
- Increase Samples. Check Properties->Render Tab->Sampling->Samples.